# Adding conditional classes to wp_get_nav_menu_items

Tags: menus

I am using wp_get_nav_menu_items to display my header menu with the code below

```
<?php
                $menu_name = 'main-menu';
                $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_name);
                foreach ($menuitems as $item ) {
                    echo '<a class="dn dib-ns poppins f7 white ml3 ml4-l header-navigation__link-item" href="'.$item->url.'">'.$item->title.'</a>';
                }
            ?>
```

I would like to add a class 'active' so I can style it differently from the other menu items when on that specific page.

How can I add a class to active menu item using the wp_get_nav_menu_items?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello just posting that I have found a solution for this using

```
<?php
  $menu_name = 'main-menu';
  $menuitems = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu_name);
  foreach ($menuitems as $item ) {
    $active_link = ( $item->object_id == get_queried_object_id() ) ? 'current' : '';
    if (!$active_link) {
      echo '<a class="dn dib-ns poppins f7 white hover-gold ml3 ml4-l header-navigation__link-item" href="'.$item->url.'">'.$item->title.'</a>';
    } else {
      echo '<a class="dn dib-ns poppins f7 white ml3 ml4-l header-navigation__link-item active" href="'.$item->url.'">'.$item->title.'</a>';
  }                   
}
?>
```